# change format of date doesn't work

Tags: php

I'd like to change the format of date from (y-m-d) to (d-m-y) but I have an error **: Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, string given in D:\wamp\www\pharmacie\vente\index.php on line 124
Call Stack**

```
if(isset($_POST['date_vente'])) {
$VenteObject = $managerVente->getListParDate(date_format($_POST['date_vente'], 'd-m-y')) ; 
echo $_POST['date_vente'] ; 
}
else {
$VenteObject = $managerVente->getList() ;
}
```

and this is the request

```
  public function getListParDate($date)
  {
    $vente = array();
    $q = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM vente where date="'.$date.'" ORDER BY id DESC ') or die(print_r($req->errorInfo()));
    $q->execute() ;

       while ($donnees = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $vente[] = new Vente($donnees);
    }
        return $vente;

  }
```

**echo $_POST['date_vente'] ;** gives y-m-d

Comment: All your answers are in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php your first problem is not thinking about the error message, Parameter 1 wants "DateTime" and not the string you fed it.

Comment: Why do you want to format it at first place? `Y-m-d` is a perfect format for mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) shows you how to use the DateTime class:

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['date_venue']);
$new_date = $date->format('d-m-y');

$VenteObject = $managerVente->getListParDate($new_date) ; 
echo $new_date;
```

Comment: Not to mention that they **don't need** to re-format date at all :-D